# Замена подстроки в строке через регулярное выражение

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, поиск, замена

Нужно составить регулярное выражение для поиска по следующему шаблону:

```
>>какие-то_числа_без_пробелов, текст
```

и замены его на

```
<a href="#какие-то_числа_без_пробелов">какие-то_числа_без_пробелов</a>, текст
```

пример:

```
>>12344, log success
<a href="#12344">12344</a>, log success
```

Совсем не идут эти эти регулярные выражения, или может материал плохой брал.

Comment: а для этого случая "1 текст 2 3", ссылка на каждое число должна быть?

Comment: И число только в начале строки может быть?

Comment: [Tag:регулярные-выражения] посмотрите описание метки. Там есть хороший материал по регексам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$s = "12345, текст";
$s = preg_replace('/^(\d+)(.*)$/', '<a href="#$1">$1</a>$2', $s);
var_dump($s);
```

Вывод

```
string '<a href="#12345">12345</a>, текст' (length=38)
```

Answer (score 1):

можно без регулярок

```
$string = explode(',',$string);
echo '<a href="'.$string[0].'" >'.$string[0].'</a>';
```

где то так разбиваем по `,` в первый(нулевой) элемент массива попадает число, и выводим его как хотим.

Answer (score 0):

Этот вариант еще смотрит что число отдельно стоит (типо 2x4):

```
$s = "123, текст 1 2x4";
$s = preg_replace('/\b(\d+)\b/', '<a href="#$1">$1</a>$2', $s);
var_dump($s);

// string(56) "<a href="#123">123</a>, текст <a href="#1">1</a> 2x4"
```